# ArrayListJavaFlightTicketsProgram

Tags: testflight, ticket-system

I have implement two classes, named a `Ticket` and `Flight`.
I have the main program is `FlightTicketsProgram` (at downside):

```
ArrayList<Ticket> tickets = new ArrayList<Ticket>();
ArrayList<Flight> flights = new ArrayList<Flight>();

Ticket ticket1 = new Ticket("201409112003", "George", "White", "TK2141");
Ticket ticket2 = new Ticket("201408182023", "John", "Clemens", "TK1852");
Ticket ticket3 = new Ticket("201409171004", "Alex", "Cats", "TK2141");
tickets.add(ticket1);
tickets.add(ticket2);
tickets.add(ticket3);

Flight flight1 = new Flight("TK2141", "THY",     "Ankara",    "Istanbul",   "25.08.2014", "14:00", "14:50");
Flight flight2 = new Flight("TK1852", "THY",     "Barselona", "Istanbul",   "15.09.2014", "05:55", "10:20");
Flight flight3 = new Flight("PC2136", "Pegasus", "Adana",     "Izmir",      "18.07.2014", "20:35", "22:40");
Flight flight4 = new Flight("DL9450", "Delta",   "Frankfurt", "Amsterdam",  "20.09.2014", "10:55", "13:00");
Flight flight5 = new Flight("KL1857", "KLM",     "Amsterdam", "Dusseldorf", "13.08.2014", "13:20", "14:30");
Flight flight6 = new Flight("PC1177", "Pegasus", "Antalya",   "Istanbul",   "22.10.2014", "10:00", "12:40");

flights.add(flight1);
flights.add(flight2);
flights.add(flight3);
flights.add(flight4);
flights.add(flight5);
flights.add(flight6);

//Step 1: print tickets
System.out.println("Tickets:");
System.out.print(ticket1);
System.out.print(ticket2);
System.out.print(ticket3);

//Step 2: print flights
System.out.println("\nExisting flights:");
System.out.println(flight1);
System.out.println(flight2);
System.out.println(flight3);
System.out.println(flight4);
System.out.println(flight5);

//Step 3: change a ticket
System.out.println("Ticket change:");
tickets.get(0).setFlightNumber("PC2136");
System.out.print(tickets.get(0));

//Step 4: change a flight
System.out.println("\nFlight change:");
flights.get(5).setDeparture("10:20");
flights.get(5).setArrival("13:00");
System.out.print(flights.get(5));
```

I have to see my output like at downside for `FlightTicketsProgram.java`.

Tickets:

```
201409112003 - TK2141 - George White
201408182023 - TK1852 - John Clemens
201409171004 - TK2141 - Alex Cats
```

Existing flights:

```
THY - TK2141 Date: 25.08.2014
From: Ankara - To: Istanbul
Departure: 14:00 - Arrival: 14:50
```

How can I do this?

Comment: show your code for Ticket and Flight class

Comment: i havent any code. i didnt start. i m asking this. i cant do anything.. :(

Comment: myprof sent me hw . it has only these

Answer (score 0):

use `toString()` in your classes `Flight` and `Ticket`

Comment: you are using Eclipse.?

Comment: right click in your Flight and Ticket class go to source>Generate toString()

Comment: Select all the fields and press OK. Then run your code